# ShareActionProvider custom icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, shareactionprovider

I implemented shareActionProvider(on ABS) with custom icon but it seems that the icon has been expanded somehow(maybe extra padding is added to the share action) and got bigger than other action items. All the action items have fixed size of 48X48 and displayed properly besides the share action. The action item looks like this:

[image]

I tried to overide activityChooserViewStyle(i think this is the component shareActionProvider is generating) but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. found the problem.
for some reason the "share" has different sizes than the other actions in the actionbar (maybe because it opens a list?).
Found it while looking at the built-in android drawable: `@drawable/abs__ic_menu_share_holo_dark`.
for that matter, in MDPI it's 32X32.

Comment: So How do I make it smaller to match other icon sizes?